# Detecting AJAX request $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] is UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm running XAMPP for linux 5.6.33

The js code:

```
var url = "send.php";
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.onload = function() {
    var decoded_response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status === 200 && xhttp.responseText && decoded_response) {
        //success
    }
    else if (xhttp.status !== 200 || !xhttp.responseText || !decoded_response) {
        //error
    }
};
xhttp.send(param);
```

my send.php file

```
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($ajax_message);

    header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    echo $encoded;

  }
  // else just display the message
  else {
    echo $message;

  }
```

From firebug I can see the request and the headers, it's all there, but the if statement is alwas false, if I add this to the else in the php code

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
echo "$name: $value\n";}
```

I can see in the response from firebug and HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is still there, so isn't being cleared somewhere in my code, but if I try

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'];
```

I get that is an undefined index

I didn't make any changes to the webserver and i don't have any .htaccess file, I can't figure out why $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header name should be `X-Requested-With`.

PHP just turns it to ALL CAPS, replaces `-` with `_` and prefixes it with `HTTP_` when it expresses it in `$_SERVER`.

You're doing that transformation manually before it gets to your JS, then PHP *does it again*.

---

`X-Requested-With` is rather a dirty hack though. I'd use something along the lines of `Accept: application/json` to request a JSON response instead of an HTML response (and look for that header in PHP).

Comment: I have used that header name before the one that I posted because it won't work event with that. And is still not working. Can you explain why is a dirty hack? Here on stack is basically the first answer you get for this type of request.

Comment: The server shouldn't care what tool is asking for the data, it should care what data (and in what format) is being asked for.

Comment: But I want to check what is asking for the data, the data that is giving out depends only on what is asking for that.